# Java Selenium - How to remove download menu from popping up with the new headless mode?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, headless

does anyone knows what is the argument to set to remove the download menu from popping up after a download is completed in Microsoft Edge using the new headless mode? My selenium program requires Microsoft Edge as the webdriver, hence I can't use Chrome or Firefox webdrivers. But if you guys have any idea, please let me know, thank you!

Have looked everywhere for a list of the arguments that I could set, but could not find any related to the disabling of the download menu from popping up.

**Edit to include example code:**

The following is an example code. In this example, the url used is the download link for the latest Microsoft Edge webdriver:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","src/main/resources/msedgedriver.exe");

    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless=new");
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--inprivate");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    // options.addArguments("___argument to disable download menu___");
        
    EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/115.0.1860.0/edgedriver_win64.zip");
}
```

**2nd Edit to include screenshot**
[image: Screenshot of Download Popup]

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code example for us to replicate it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KendrickLi Hi I have edited and provided an example of the code to replicate it

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your code, but I didn't see any download menu pop up after my download completed. Could you please provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: @KendrickLi Hi my apologies for replying late. I have edited the post to include a screenshot of the MS Edge menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to have this browser UI when I'm in the new headless mode, but if you want to prevent that downloads menu, you can try the following code:

```
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("browser.show_hub_popup_on_download_start", false);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem's solved now.